# Google Big Query: Get New Visitor Count using Custom Dimension

Tags: google-bigquery

```
select   PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', t.date) as Date
        ,count(distinct(fullvisitorid)) as User
       ,SUM( totals.newVisits ) AS New_Visitors
       ,(if(customDimensions.index=1, customDimensions.value,null))  as Orig
FROM `table` as t
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hit
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hit.customDimensions ) AS customDimensions  
group by Date, orig
```

Is there a way to get new visitor count and use the customDimension at the same time? The sum(total.newVisits) doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
SELECT DATE 
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT(fullvisitorid)) AS User
  ,SUM( newVisits ) AS New_Visitors
  ,Orig
FROM (
  SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', t.date) AS DATE
    ,fullvisitorid
    ,totals.newVisits AS newVisits
    ,(IF(customDimensions.index=1, customDimensions.value,NULL))  AS Orig
  FROM `table` AS t
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hit
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hit.customDimensions ) AS customDimensions  
  GROUP BY DATE, orig, fullvisitorid, newVisits
)
GROUP BY DATE, Orig
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way in your case is to remove the cross-joins and use sub-selects instead:

```sql
SELECT
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', t.date) AS Date
  ,(SELECT value FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) WHERE index=1) Orig
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT(fullvisitorid)) AS User
  ,SUM( totals.newVisits ) AS New_Visitors
FROM
  `table` t
GROUP BY Orig, Date
```

In case you have a dimension on hit scope and really need to flatten the table, you need to build a session id you can count distinct. That is because you are repeating all session scoped fields on hit-scope by applying the cross-join:

```sql
SELECT
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', t.date) AS Date
  ,(SELECT value FROM h.customDimensions WHERE index=2) justAHitCd
  ,h.page.pagePathLevel1
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT(fullvisitorid)) AS User

  -- create session id and count distinct
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitstarttime AS STRING)) ) AS all_sessions

  -- only count distinct session id of sessions where totals.newVisits = 1
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT 
    IF(totals.newVisits=1, 
      CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitstarttime AS STRING)), 
      NULL )
   ) AS New_Visitors

FROM
  -- flatten table to hit scope (comma means cross-join in stnd sql)
  `table` t, t.hits h
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

So in case for new visitors I only provide a session id if totals.newVisits=1 - else the if-statement provides `NULL` which is not countable.

If you have something similar on product-scope, you'd need to create an ID that takes into account session and hit.
E.g. counting pages for productSku:

```sql
SELECT
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', t.date) AS Date
  ,(SELECT value FROM h.customDimensions WHERE index=2) justAHitCd
  ,p.productSku
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT fullvisitorid) AS users
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitstarttime AS STRING))) AS sessions
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT 
    IF(h.type='PAGE',
      CONCAT(fullvisitorid, cast(visitstarttime AS STRING),CAST(hitNumber AS STRING)),
      NULL)  
  ) as pageviews
  ,COUNT(1) AS products
FROM
  `table` t, t.hits h LEFT JOIN h.product p
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Note, that I'm left joining the product array. Since it sometimes is empty a cross-join would destroy all hits information: cross-join with empty table results in empty table.

Hope that helps!